# Possible conflict between eledmac-eledpar and the BibLaTeX footnote-dw style (biblatex-dw package)

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, eledmac, biblatex-dw, eledpar

In the MWE below I'm trying to typeset a citation embedded in a footnote with the BibLaTeX style `footnote-dw`. All's well if I do not load the package `eledmac`. As soon as I do, the citation within the footnote issues another footnote (not typeset anymore), whereas I want the citation in the same footnote where it was originally issued. But I need `eledmac`, together with `eledpar`, for my "real-life" document, and the facilities of the `footnote-dw` package are so well-tuned to my requirements that I would like to keep it.  Is there a way to circumvent this conflict?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Biblio.bib}
  @BOOK{RefA,
   author =       {AuthorA},
   title =        {TitleA},
   publisher =    {PubA},
   year =         {1900},
 }

 @BOOK{RefB,
  author =       {AuthorB},
  title =        {TitleB},
  publisher =    {PubB},
  year =         {1800},
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{eledmac} %<- Comment to avoid issue
%\usepackage{eledpar}

\usepackage[
  style = footnote-dw,
  pageref = true,
  xref=true,
  backend = biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
  This is plain filler\cite{RefA} and further on 
  now with a footnote\footnote{A text with a citation to be typeset here \cite{RefB}. 
 But how?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's too late for me to explore the deeper interactions, but the basic problem is that the `\iffootnote` test is failing (presumably because `\eledmac` does complex things to footnotes that `biblatex` doesn't understand/know.  Workaround: put a `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` before your `\cite{RefB}`.

Comment: @jon: You are right: it works. As you say, it is more of a workaround than of a full-fledged solution, though.

Comment: Indeed, as @moewe and @jon said the problem is that eledmac change the definition of `\@footnotetxt`. Biblatex takes care to this modification, but use a way which can't work when also using `memoir` (limit of the `patchcmd` command). So I have changes the way `eledmac` patches the footnote commands. Could you try the branch `issue232` ? the handbook is  at https://github.com/maieul/ledmac#debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version 1.16.0 of eledmac (now in CTAN) solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `eledmac` changes the definitions of the `\footnote` commands (especially `\@footnotetext`) in a way that `biblatex` cannot change it to include `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}`, but we can do that for `biblatex` with a few lines of code

```
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@footnotetext}{\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{eledmac}
%\usepackage{eledpar}
\usepackage[
  style = footnote-dw,
  pageref = true,
  xref=true,
  backend = biber
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@footnotetext}{\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}{}{}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  This is plain filler\cite{wilde} and further on 
  now with a footnote\footnote{A text with a citation to be typeset here \cite{cicero}. But how?}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this patchs has a problem : the `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` is added outside of the `begin@color` group, and I am afraid by some boarding effects.

Comment: @Maïeul: Shall I wait for further news from you before accepting any answer? The toggle works but I understand that, as it is so far, it is just a workaround until becoming fully integrated in the `eledmac` package itself.

Comment: yes, you should. I have posted a comment after your question, to ask you to try new version of eledmac (in dev).

Comment: @Maïeul: I'm afrid I cannot proceed now, but I'll go asap today. Thanks so much.

Comment: there is no emergency :)

Comment: do you think to have time to try before friday? I would like to publish a new version friday...

Comment: @Maïeul: Sorry about the delay. I ran `pdflaTex` on the .dtx file but couldn't get the .sty file. I tried with an .ins file but got the same problem: Checksum not passed (10594<>10595). A bunch of files waas spanned, though, including .pdf, .toc, etc. Any hint?

Comment: to obtain the .sty, run the .ins file. You don't need yet the new version of the .pdf :-). I will change the checksum at the publicatio, because checksum change at each debug, and so I do it in one time.

Comment: @Maïeul: I have just tested it against my MWE and it works fine. I still have to check it with my complete project, but I guess it will work alright, too. Shall you provide an answer so that I can check it as the full solution?

Comment: Yes, it should be a full solution.

Comment: @Maïeul: In my project I'm getting the following error message that I didn't get before using the new .sty file (after a couple of "Enter" keystrokes the document compiles fine, though): Package eledmac Warning: \advanceline produced a line number less than zero. on input line 2.
)
! Extra \fi.
\line@list@stuffR ...nenum@outR =#1\relax \fi \fi

Comment: strange. I am not sur that is link with this problem. Please send me by email your example.

Comment: please, for this point, use the github forum.

Comment: please, send my your file by email. I coulnd't debug  with it. My email : first name at first name dot net

Comment: @Marcos: some news for this problem?

Comment: @Marcos: for this question issue, problem is solved. for the "produced a line number less than zero. on input line", I think you should open an issue on github, because we can't solve it in this forum.